# How to convert binary input to characters?

Tags: python, binary, type-conversion, binaryfiles

I have a program that reads in binary data. The data represents numbers in the form of a character (value between 0 and 256). I am able to read in the file in Python. However, I would like to extract from the file one particular cells value. This is where I'm stuck. **How do I do this? So I want for example the character on place 100 made readable in an integer or float.**

The code I currently have:

```
def read_data(filename):
    if filename.endswith(".gz"):
        f = gzip.open(filename, "rb")
    else:
        f = open(filename, "rb")
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    # HERE SHOULD BE A COMMAND THAT PRINTS OUT THE VALUE OF AN ELEMENT IN THE FILE
    return content
```

Any help would be appreciated. It seems like a basic question, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere on the site. A link to a working solution is therefore also fine.

Comment: can you share what the input looks like?

Comment: `content[100]`?

Comment: The answer is based on what the `read()` returns, but that changes from python2 to python3 - can you specify which python version you're using?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound Is there a way to attach input-files? .gz are compressed files. Opening them in a text editor just gives ^R^R^R^R^R^R^R^R^R^R. But after unpacking them with the code I wrote it should be something like "0000 0110 1110 0000" but then for close to 1 million numbers.

Comment: What does `print(repr(content[:42]))` print?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I tried that, that just gives me the 100th binary number and displays a square in my terminal after printing, like [00\\12] (sorry, no better way to make this visible). How do I get this in a number?

Comment: @DanielleM. I'm currently using python 2.7 for that particular script.

Comment: @StefanPochmann print(repr(content[:42])) gives me '\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12'

Comment: So `ord(content[100])` then?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Brilliant, that does the trick. I never heard of the command 'ord'. I'll have to look that one up.

Comment: @StefanPochmann If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it as the correct one as apparently I can't accept comments as answers...